# C++ features not available with /clr

Tags: c++-cli, clr

When programming in C++/CLI, you occassionally receive compilation errors, since some C++ features (like `std::thread` for instance) are not supported when compiling with `/clr`.

I wonder if there is a (resonably up-to-date) document clarifying *which* C++ constructs are not possible in managed code? Does anybody have a link or a hint where to find something?

Just to make clear: I'm pretty aware that in a managed class, i.e. `ref class` etc., the subset of possible C++ features is restricted even further. My question is targeting ordinary unmanaged code that happens to be compiled with `/clr` switched on.

Comment: Yuck, a list question.  It is moving target with C++11 and C++14 and C++1z around.  Basic starting point is to assume that C++03 compliant code is fine and most everything that was added later is not.  And assuming that you are probably making a mistake compiling existing C++ code with /clr in effect.  Favor the built-in support for interop, consider #pragma managed to switch back-and-forth on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a "Migrate to clr" guide, try reading it for a start.